# Laravel, Detach() method to delete parent records

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Hi guys I'm working with many to many relationship and I want to know if is there any way to delete the records of the main table.

These are my tables

```
  Schema::create('inventario_inicial', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('producto_nombre_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('producto_nombre_id')->references('id')->on('producto_nombre');
        $table->integer('existencias');
        $table->double('promedio');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
    Schema::create('empresa_inventario_inicial', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('empresa_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('empresa_id')->references('id')->on('empresas');
        $table->integer('inventario_inicial_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('inventario_inicial_id')->references('id')->on('inventario_inicial');
    });
```

I can get the data via pivot with this code

```
$empresa = Empresa::find($request->empresa_id);
$empresa->inventario_inicial();
```

To detach the data of that `$empresa` i use  `$empresa->inventario_inicial()->detach();`

It deletes the records of the pivot table witch is correct, but also I want to delete not only what's in `empresa_inventario_inicial` but also `inventario_inicial` that were related. Something like cascade deleting but from pivot table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$table->foreign('inventario_inicial_id')->references('id')->on('inventario_inicial')->onDelete('cascade')` in your migration.

If you don't want to cascade, consider using model [events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#events) to automatically detach any `empresa_inventario_official` pivot records when deleting an `inventario_official`, and then use the `$empresa->inventario_inicial()->delete()` method in place of your `detach()` above.

In `App\InventarioOfficial`:

```
protected $dispatchesEvents = ['deleting' => InventarioDeleting::class];
```

Then you can define the event and a listener for the event:

In `App\Events\InventarioDeleting`

```
class InventarioDeleting
{
    use SerializesModels;

    public $inventario_official;

    public function __construct(InventarioOfficial $inventario_official)
    {
       $this->inventario_official = $inventario_official;
    }
}
```

In `App\Providers\EventServiceProvider`

```
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    Event::listen(\App\Events\InventarioDeleting::class, function ($io) {
        DB::('empresa_inventario_inicial')->where('inventario_inicial_id',$io->id)->delete();
        //or $io->empresas()->detach();
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi, thx for the answer, this would work if I delete an specific record in my `inventario_inicial`, the thing is that if I use `detach()`, id like that all records get deleted not only in my pivot table but in the main one, cascade works if I delete a record in that table. Is there a way to do that??

Comment: I'm suggesting that you approach the other way around, i.e. you delete the `inventario_inicial` and this triggers a delete of all the attached `empresa`. Is there a reason this wouldn't work?